# TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined --reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a tabcontainer component (child)uncontrolled component actually i dont know i'm doing it the right way and content component(parent)

contents.js

```
class Contents extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static" color="default">
          <Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            scrollable
            scrollButtons="on"
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
          >
            <Tab label="Wallet" />
            <Tab label="Transactions" />
            <Tab label="Add Fund" />
            <Tab label="Withdraw" />
            <Tab label="Add Bank Account" />
            <Tab label="Transfer" />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
        {value === 1 && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
        {value === 2 && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
        {value === 3 && <TabContainer>Item Four</TabContainer>}
        {value === 4 && <TabContainer>Item Five</TabContainer>}
        {value === 5 && <TabContainer>Item Six</TabContainer>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

tabcontainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const TabContainer = props => {
  return (
    <Typography component="div" style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {this.props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
};

TabContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default TabContainer;
```

I get the following error   **TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined --reactjs**.

I dont know whether I'm using props the right way passing in function **prototype** or I need **class**.

Can anyone lemme know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: you cannot use `this.props` in functional components, instead try `props.children`

Comment: props.children works. can you please explain why not use "this.props"

Comment: Only class components have props set to `this.props`, functional components as you see have an argument passed to them

Comment: even without constructor it works the state has no this how is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
   <Typography component="div" style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
                {props.children}
   </Typography>
```

Don't use this.props in functional component.